# How intercept response and modify response body with play framework 2.2.x?

Tags: java, filter, httpresponse, playframework-2.2, interceptor

I need to intercept request and response. I have already intercepted request.
But I cant intercept response and get response body with java.
I need to intercept response in play framework 2.2.x with java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Action Composition to intercept the request/response. You would write your own composition. Please take a look https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaActionsComposition

Comment: How can i get response from delegate.call(context)?

Comment: Create response object `Response response = context.response()` in your public F.Promise<Result> call(Http.Context context) method and use response object to access the methods.

Comment: I used context.response() but I can't get response body. I can only access the headers. <br> Is there to get response body.

Comment: There is no way to get response body in Action or Action composition in any server side language. Since Play is not a component based MVC architecture.

Comment: The business logic needs to be done can be taken to BaseController or something